# Eclipse TFS issue

Tags: java, eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin

Getting the following error in eclipse. I am using TFS eclipse plugin.

> Error occurred in wizard completion. More details are available in the
>   Eclipse Patform log.
>
> TF400018: The local version table for the local workspace  could not be opened.com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.exceptions.WorkspaceVersionTableException.

Please give an idea on how to solve this issue

Comment: Can you give more context to the code that gives you this error?

Comment: I am getting this error while I am trying to connect to TFS from Eclipse Luna IDE in a fresh workspace.